# Running a native program in Adobe AIR

Tags: windows, macos, air

I need to run a native program and retrieve the output in an Adobe AIR client side only application. I know that AIR does not allow access to native applications, so what is the best way to achieve this? I came across [this](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=4&postId=11187) solution which works on Windows, but I need something that works on Mac as well. I'd rather not have two separate solutions if possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: How does the native program produce its output?  In other words, in this a console program that sends output to stdout, or are you trying to "scrape" a program with a graphical user interface?

Comment: yeah, it's just a console program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that [Shu](http://www.shu-player.com/) might be what you're looking for.  It costs money, but its an API and bundler for AIR applications that gives them additional functionality.

To quote their site:

> Shu provides you the developer with a
>   toolkit of commands to extend the
>   system capabilities of your AIR
>   application, features include,
>   controlling external applications,
>   opening external files, database
>   connectivity and control, system path
>   retrieval and screen capture
>   functionality.

I believe that its cross platform as well.

Comment: Its not cross platform, I have it, you can turn any .air into an executable for EITHER mac or windows or you can make one for each, but you cannot make a single file that is cross os.

Answer (score 0):

Also see

http://www.merapiproject.net/

http://aperture.fluorinefx.com/