# Is it possible to start a native application from Adobe Air?

Tags: air, native

Is it possible to start a native application/service from Adobe Air?

I guess this is basically a duplicate of [Running a native program in Adobe AIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422225/running-a-native-program-in-adobe-air), but that question is a year old so hopefully the answer is now "yes"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from AIR 2.0, yes - [NativeProcessInfo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html). It will be supported if your application supports **extendedDesktop** profile and is compiled as native installer.